# format search string in django admin search

Tags: django, search, django-admin

I am using the out-of-the-box django admin search on my django model.  One of my use cases is to look up an object from a barcode scan.  The problem is that the barcodes have a bunch of leading zeroes, which prevent the query from returning the correct barcode.

My solution was to override the admin/search_form.html template, and to apply a custom template filter to format the string before the query executes.  I wrote a custom template filter called stripLeadingZeroes, and I can succesfully load it. I then override the search_form template, and used my custom template filter on **cl.query**....changing it to **cl.query|stripLeadingZeroes** With these edits, the query executes, returns no result due to the leading zeroes, and THEN applies the filter after the query has already been executed.

**How can I format the string in advance of the query?**

Here is the line that I changed in the search_form template

```
<input type="text" size="40" name="{{ search_var }}" value="{{ cl.query|stripLeadingZeroes }}" id="searchbar" />
```

Comment: You should try to remove all unneeded code from your example: use the minimal code required for the reader to understand.

Comment: Straight template logic can't do this.  You have to either preprocess your query string before submitting it (using some javascript) or change the way your admin understands the query string by giving your admin model a custom ChangeList class.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I am looking into this now.

Comment: If you do a custom ChangeList, look into overriding its `get_query_set` method, and in particular its self.query attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to override ModelAdmin.get_search_results as suggested in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results).

```
class OccurrenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['barcode','description']
    search_fields = ['description']

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        try: 
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(barcode=search_term_as_int)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Converting the search string to an integer automatically strips the leading zeros.

Comment: nice approach!  I will accept this answer....your use-case is very similar to mine!